# What is my overall grade percentage score?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I received 20/30 for one assignment worth 30% of the overall mark. 21/30 for the second, which is worth 30% of the overall mark. And 15.5/40 for the third which is worth 40%. What is my overall grade percentage?

Comment: 20+21+15.5=56.5

Comment: There is a joke somewhere here about Xzibit.

Answer (score 1):

$$.3*(20/30)+.3*(21/30)+.4*(15.5/40) = .565 = 56.5\%$$

I'd be a tad worried if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply each grade by its "weight" (how much, as a percentage of the overall mark, it is work) and add these products together. Note that $30 \% = 30/100 = 0.3$ and $40 \% = 40/100 = 0.4$.

$$\frac{20}{30} \cdot 0.3 + \frac{21}{30} \cdot 0.3 + \frac{15.5}{40} \cdot 0.4 = 0.565 = 56.5 \%$$

I hope this isn't *your* grade :)